# Error: while inserting Json into Postgresql with Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm trying to insert some values into my table. Because I'm pretty new to Python and PostgreSQL, I'm getting many different errors. That's why I would firstly present what I have.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vuln
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL,
    pde json,
    "pde_ID" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    pde_published boolean,
    pde_references json[],
    pde_description json,
    pde_impact json,
    pde_cwe text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    pde_valid boolean,
    pde_published_date date,
    pde_eval_has boolean,
    pde_products_has_inc_excl boolean,
    pde_products json[],
    CONSTRAINT vuln_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

My insert query:

```
  for vul_item in myList:
        query = """INSERT INTO vuln (pde, "pde_ID", pde_description, pde_published, pde_published_date, pde_valid, pde_cwe, 
        pde_references, pde_products, pde_eval_has_exploit, pde_vulnerable_products_has_inc_excl, pde_impact) 
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s);"""
        data = (vul_item.pde, vul_item.pde_ID, vul_item.pde_description, vul_item.pde_published,
                vul_item.pde_published_date, vul_item.pde_valid, vul_item.pde_cwe, vul_item.pde_references,
                vul_item.pde_products, vul_item.pde_eval_has_exploit,
                vul_item.pde_products_has_inc_excl, vul_item.pde_impact)
        print(data)
        cr.execute(query, data)
        cr.commit()
```

I'm getting following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 3: ...and a lot of other things."}]}}', 'PDE-201-2930', 'The....
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "The" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON-Daten, Zeile 1: the...
```

The type of Json variables in my Python code are:

> < class 'str' >

Because I convert them (dict variable) via with `json.dumps()` to Json. I also verified my Json items, they have no syntax errors.

And this is the vul_item.pde Json:

```
{"data_type": "PDE", "data_format": "MITRE", "data_version": "4.0", "PDE_data_meta": {"ID": "PDE-0001", "ASSIGNER": "PDE@pde.org"}, "problemtype": {"problemtype_data": [{"description": [{"lang": "en", "value": "PWE-200"}]}]}, "references": {"reference_data": [{"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "200110 More information regarding ", "refsource": "VULNWATCH", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "20030110 More information regarding Etherleak", "refsource": "BUGTRAQ", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "7996", "refsource": "SECUNIA", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "A010603-1", "refsource": "ATSTAKE", "tags": ["Vendor Advisory"]}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "http://www.ccc.com", "refsource": "MISC", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "VU#412115", "refsource": "CERT-VN", "tags": ["Third Party Advisory", "Resource"]}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "http://ccc.com", "refsource": "CONFIRM", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.osvdb.org/9962", "name": "9962", "refsource": "OSVDB", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "RHSA-2003:025", "refsource": "REDHAT", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "RHSA-2003:088", "refsource": "REDHAT", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "no info here", "refsource": "BUGTRAQ", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "20030117 Re: More information regarding Etherleak", "refsource": "BUsRAQ", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.ccc.com", "name": "1031583", "refsource": "SECssRACK", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://ccc.com", "name": "104185", "refsource": "SECTRACK", "tags": []}, {"url": "https://ccc.com", "name": "oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665", "refsource": "OVAL", "tags": []}]}, "description": {"description_data": [{"lang": "en", "value": "The description of this product is not published."}]}}
```

When i also try to insert just this json into table, i get the same error.

Comment: It looks as though it's complaining that 'ip_input' is not valid JSON, and that is true.  Please provide the contents of vul_item so that it's easier for people to help you.  Ideally provide runnable code.

Comment: I changed it, thanks.

Comment: Since vul_item.pde does not contain "ip_input", it's probably not related to the error you're getting.  I recommend posting the entire contents of vul_item.

Comment: I changed it once again. In this case I'm getting "Token 'The' not found. It's actually not a token, it contains a string. the contents of vul_item is exactly the same with vul_item.pde. When i also just insert the vul_item.pde I get the same error.

Comment: The variables which i convert via with json.dumps()  are dict. Do you think this is the reason?